# Пересобрать массив, вынести значение в индекс

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

Есть массив $orders вида:

```
0 => 
array (size=4)
  'id' => string '9' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Персик' (length=12)
  'price' => string '16' (length=2)
  'id_order' => string '1935669060' (length=10)
1 => 
array (size=4)
  'id' => string '9' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Персик' (length=12)
  'price' => string '16' (length=2)
  'id_order' => string '1935669060' (length=10)
 3 => 
 array (size=4)
  'id' => string '9' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'Персик' (length=12)
  'price' => string '16' (length=2)
  'id_order' => string '1034208938' (length=10)
```

Как мне id_order вынести в индекс массива, чтобы получилось что-то типа

```
    1935669060 =>
        array (size=2)
            0 => 
            array (size=3)
              'id' => string '9' (length=1)
              'name' => string 'Персик' (length=12)
              'price' => string '16' (length=2)
            1 => 
            array (size=3)
              'id' => string '9' (length=1)
              'name' => string 'Персик' (length=12)
              'price' => string '16' (length=2)
    1034208938 = >
        array (size=1)
             0 => 
             array (size=3)
              'id' => string '9' (length=1)
              'name' => string 'Персик' (length=12)
              'price' => string '16' (length=2)
```

То есть, чтобы мне потом было удобно вывести товар по номеру заказа.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $new_order[$order['id_order']][] = ['id'=>$order['id'], 'name'=>$order['name'], 'price'=>$order['price']];
        }
```